# No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous??(template)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, templates

I am making generic vector class with template

I almost finished them

but this **vector.push_back(element);** line let constructor tell me it is ambiguous.

edit:ok, so I put the whole code

the problem was below:

(222): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous(its push_back function which I put (222) in front of that line)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class BasicVector
{
private:
    int vector_size;
    int vector_capacity;
    T* data;

    void resize();

public:
    BasicVector() {};
    BasicVector(int);
    ~BasicVector();

    T& at(int);
    T& operator[](int);
    T& front();
    T& back();

    void push_back(T);
    void insert(int, T);
    void pop_back();

    int size();
    int capacity();

    void print();
};


template <typename T>
void BasicVector<T>::resize()
{
    T* temp = data;
    T* newDataCap = new T[vector_capacity * 2];
    this->data = newDataCap;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = temp[i];
    }
    vector_capacity *= 2;
    delete[] temp;
}

template <typename T>
BasicVector<T>::BasicVector(int capacity)
{
    if (capacity < 16)
    {
        capacity = 16;
    }
    else if (capacity >= 16 && capacity % 2 == 1)
    {
        capacity = capacity + 1;
    }
    vector_capacity = capacity;
    data = new T[vector_capacity];
    vector_size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
BasicVector<T>::~BasicVector()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
    delete[] data;
}

template <typename T>
T& BasicVector<T>::at(int elemNumber)
{
    if (elemNumber > vector_size)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return data[elemNumber];
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& BasicVector<T>::operator[](int elemNumber)
{
    if (elemNumber > vector_size)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return data[elemNumber];
    }
}

template <typename T>
T& BasicVector<T>::front()
{
    return data[0];
}

template <typename T>
T& BasicVector<T>::back()
{
    return data[vector_size];
}

template <typename T>
void BasicVector<T>::push_back(T element)
{
    if (vector_size == vector_capacity)
    {
        resize();
    }
    data[vector_size] = element;
    vector_size++;
}

template <typename T>
void BasicVector<T>::insert(int  elemNum, T element)
{
    if (vector_size == vector_capacity)
    {
        resize();
    }
    int* temp = new int[vector_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = data[elemNum + i - 1];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < vector_size; j++)
    {
        data[elemNum + j] = temp[j];
    }

    data[elemNum - 1] = element;

    vector_size++;

    delete[] temp;
}

template <typename T>
void BasicVector<T>::pop_back()
{
    data[vector_size] = 0;
    vector_size--;
}

template <typename T>
int BasicVector<T>::size()
{
    return vector_size;
}

template <typename T>
int BasicVector<T>::capacity()
{
    return vector_capacity;
}

template <typename T>
void BasicVector<T>::print()
{
    cout << "elements(" << vector_size << "):";
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << data[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void theCoolFunction(BasicVector<T> &vector)
{
    cout << "Now accepting commands (quit to exit program): "<< endl;

    string choice;
    while (choice != "quit")
    {
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == "get")
        {
            int elemNum;
            cin >> elemNum;
            cout << vector[elemNum] << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "at")
        {
            int elemNum;
            cin >> elemNum;
            cout << vector.at(elemNum) << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "front")
        {
            cout << "The first element of the vector is: " << vector.front() << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "back")
        {
            cout << "The last element of the vector is: " << vector.back() << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "insert")
        {
            int  elemNum, element;
            cin >> elemNum >> element;
            vector.insert(elemNum, element);
        }
        else if (choice == "push")
        {
            int element;
            cin >> element;
       (222)vector.push_back(element);
        }
        else if (choice == "pop")
        {
            vector.pop_back();
        }
        else if (choice == "size")
        {
            cout << vector.size() << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "capacity")
        {
            cout << vector.capacity() << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == "print")
        {
            vector.print();
        }
        else if (choice == "quit")
        {
            cout << "Exiting Program." << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "invalid input" << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int dataType;
    cout << "Specify what data type to store in vector:" << endl;
    cout << "1) int" << endl;
    cout << "2) float" << endl;
    cout << "3) dou! ble" << endl;
    cout << "4) string" << endl;
    cout << "5) bool" << endl;
    cin >> dataType;

    int capacity;
    cout << "Enter starting capacity of vector: ";
    cin >> capacity;
    cout << endl;


    if (dataType == 1)
    {
        BasicVector<int>vector(capacity);
        theCoolFunction<int>(vector);
    }
    else if (dataType == 2)
    {
        BasicVector<float>vector(capacity);
        theCoolFunction<float>(vector);
    }
    else if (dataType == 3)
    {
        BasicVector<double>vector(capacity);
        theCoolFunction<double>(vector);
    }
    else if (dataType == 4)
    {
        BasicVector<string>vector(capacity);
        theCoolFunction<string>(vector);
    }
    else if (dataType == 5)
    {
        BasicVector<bool>vector(capacity);
        theCoolFunction<bool>(vector);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post all code, and the exact error message.

Comment: yes, I just put the whole code

Comment: All of the things you're trying to insert, push_back, etc are ints. Can an int implicitly convert to a string? If you're going to use a template you need to use the templated type. The actual error is obviously much more than you posted here and it includes the exact type that is the problem.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }` should be removed from destructor. And you break rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: Here's a syntactically correct version of your problem areas. Short answer, if you mean `T`, use `T` not `int`. I leave the debugging up to you. https://ideone.com/x86gGM

Comment: @RetiredNinja That looks like an answer